# How in Qt are handle the cursor shape relative to cursor position?

Tags: c++, qt, cursor

Watching the Qt source code, I can't see where the cursor shape is changed when the mouse pointer move, there is nothing in mouseMoveEvent, neither enterEvent.

What I would like to do is a widget where the mouse cursor change depending the mouse position, but without have to put fake widgets nor set a global cursor (unless it is the only solution). But before that, I want to understand how Qt manage that.

Comment: Let me make sure I understood correctly. You want to know how you can change the mouse cursor shape depending on the mouse position on a widget?

Comment: yes, this is the my end, but I also want to understand how Qt do it itself (to not to have to handle it in mouse move event)

Comment: I think I have a solution for you, see my answer. Please tell if my example suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [mouseMoveEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) or [install an event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for your widget and for certain mouse positions you can change the mouse cursor using the [QCuror](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcursor.html) API.

Here is an example:

*CursorChange.pro:*

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = CursorChange
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
           widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h
```

*widget.h:*

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

*widget.cpp:*

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QCursor>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->pos().x() < geometry().width() / 2)
    {
        setCursor(QCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor));
    }
    else
    {
        setCursor(QCursor(Qt::WaitCursor));
    }

    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

*main.cpp:*

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This way, when you hover the mouse pointer in the left half of the widget you will have a *hand* mouse cursor, and if you hover the mouse pointer in the right side of the widget you will get a *wait* mouse cursor.

Comment: "But before that, I want to understand how Qt manage that."
<--- that means I didn't want a solution how to do it this way (a simple google search would have found a similar answer)
In Qt sources, I didn't see any code like this, so where is it implemented ?

Comment: @hl037_ Where is implemented what? What were you searching in the Qt sources? You want to understand how Windows implements such a feature? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Careful, as this answer will propagate the cursor to child widgets.